# Can a Waddle Dee finish a race before Kirby?

Tags: kirbys-dream-buffet

In a Battle Royale match Races in Kirby's Dream Buffet include 4 AI controlled Waddle Dees that are typically inconsequential to a race as they get left behind early. Let's say you had a private match where all 4 Kirby players decided to let the Waddle Dees win instead. Would the Waddle Dees be able to finish the race and eat the strawberry piles at the finish line?

[image: 4 Waddle Dees at the start of a race]

Comment: I think that's their real purpose: suppose that every player is so (deliberately or not) bad that they can't end the race, the Waddle Dees will eventually reach the goal and finish the race.